# Add additional property to application user ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am learning ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF. I want each registered user to be able to create a simple list of their belonging items.

So I have an `Item` class in `Model` folder:

```
class Item 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How can I update my database using code first approach so that user can have a foreign key to `Items` table so that I can query all items that belong to the current user?

```
Select * 
From Items 
Where userID = currentUserID
```

Comment: To be honest. use ASP.NET Identity 2.2. it handles everything you need about user Authorization or Authentication. You can even extend it to use your own entities for user profile. It'll use EF(code-first) as well tho it has its own dbcontext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have `item` as a separate `entity(Model)` then create a relationship with the `user`. When you use this approach EF will create respective tables with their relationships(one to many i.e one user can have many entities).

Here is how its implemented in code.

**Item Class**

```
public class Item 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   //foreign key
   public int UserId {get; set;}

   //Navigation property 
   public virtual ApplicationUser User{get; set;}
}
```

**Application user class**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //Here you can add more properties if you wish to
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //User-Item relationship (user can have many Items)
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will have to go to `ApplicationDbContext` and add `DbSet` of `Item` as below

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<SchedulerUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    //some code are excluded for clarity
}
```

To get the list of all items that belong to the user you can query using linq like

```
var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var Items = _db.Users.Find(UserId).Items.ToList();
```